# Run the .exe with arguments but also check if it exists on Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, parameters, arguments, exe

I stayed up all night trying to find an answer with no luck.

I'm very new to coding overall so this problem is probably laughed at, but anyway :)

I'm making a launcher to an .exe file with Visual Basic. The launcher is very simple and it has few buttons. One of the buttons checks if the .exe exists in the correct path, if it doesn't, it shows an error window and if it does, it runs the .exe. However this program needs parameters/arguments to work properly and since I don't have parameters the program itself gives an error. How do I add the parameters after the .exe?

Here's my code:

````
        Try
            If Shell(Application.StartupPath & "\program.exe") Then
                Me.Close()

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("File not found!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        End Try
    End Sub```
````

Comment: Don't use `Shell` in VB.NET. It's a VB6 holdover. Call `Peocess.Start` instead and, if you read the documentation for that method, it will be obvious how to pass commandline arguments.

Comment: By the way, call the cryptically-named `File.Exists` method to determine whether a file exists.

Comment: Finally, call `Path.Combine` to combine partial file and folder paths.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code :

```
    Try
        If File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\program.exe") Then
            Process.Start(Application.StartupPath & "\program.exe","arguments")
            Me.Close()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("File not found!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    End Try
```

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: Tried it but got this error on the Process.Start line: 'File' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: @user6681334 `Import System.IO`

Comment: Thanks, I added that line right in the beginning of the code. The program now runs with the arguments, however for some reason the error box "File not found" does not show up at all, when the .exe is missing. Any ideas why?

Comment: @user6681334 So you have `Imports System.IO` and you still can't access the `File` class or do you mean the path of the target fie? Anyways, Use the `Dim target = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "program.exe")` and pass the variable to the methods.

Comment: No. The program works and launches but the MsgBox "File not found" does not show up when the file is missing.

Comment: I fixed it by adding another if: ```If Not File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\program.exe") Then
            MsgBox("File not found!.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        End If```